# Can I work with only PYC files

Tags: python

I have a program that uses couple of PY files. The code works perfectly till I use the PY files. However, for encryption when I delete the PY files and just keep the PYC files the program fails with message:
**ImportError: No module named abc**

Any ideas/thoughts why python does not like the PYC here when everyting was working fine with the PY files?

Comment: maybe all the pyc files weren't generated.

Comment: "for encryption when I delete the PY files and just keep the PYC files" That's... not how it's done. pyc files aren't just encrypted versions of py files.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Infact I did not delete all PY files only some that were supposed to be encrypted. Does it mean that I would loose some data if I use pyc's?Any ideas to how I could generate desired pyc's for my purpose?

Comment: using .pyc for "encryption" is security through obscurity....

Answer (score 4):

`.pyc` files contain byte-compiled python. These can be de-compiled again into very readable python code, and are not a protection from people studying the source code.

If you do want to use this, you need to make sure *all* files are compiled, use:

```
python -m compileall /path/to/package
```

before removing the `.py` source files.

Comment: Apologies, but that does not help. Does the compile process in some way distorts the information in the PYC files making it unreadable for python?

Comment: @user741592: No; the compile process makes the information *more* readable to python; the internal representation (byte code) is stored in them. It's just that that representation can be turned back into python source code readable to humans with relative ease.